# Replicating an answering machine in C# or C++ with TAPI 3.1 or AT Commands

Tags: c#, at-command, voice, telecommunication, tapi

Figured my question was too vague so going to make smaller questions asking more specific details.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/481f439f-5f54-4e5f-9c13-cba407d2597f/answering-machine-playrecord-wave?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it no longer contains a question.